# How to Create a generic function to the following code using array

Tags: javascript

How can I create a generic function for the following code using an array

```
function checkTermDuration(id) {
    var days = "Days"
    if (id == days) {
        document.getElementById('termPurchase:maturityDateInputDate').value = "";
        document.getElementById('termPurchase:selectDate:1').checked = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('termPurchase:day').value = "";
        document.getElementById('termPurchase:months').value = "";
        document.getElementById('termPurchase:years').value = "";
        document.getElementById('termPurchase:selectDate:0').checked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: _offtopic:_ using colons in element ID names ? o_O

Comment: What would the array contain? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Its totally unclear what you're asking. Also, a method named something like `checkTermDuration` should actually check something, you're just setting a load of fields to (i presume) some default state. In which case the method should be called something like `clearTermDurationFields`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "generic function", but I've made it table driven so all the varying data is in a couple arrays:

```
var data1 = [
    {name: 'day', field: 'value', value: ""},
    {name: 'months', field: 'value', value: ""},
    {name: 'years', field: 'value', value: ""},
    {name: 'selectDate:0', field: 'checked', value: true}
];

var data2 = [
    {name: 'maturityDateInputDate', field: 'value', value: ""},
    {name: 'selectDate:1', field: 'checked', value: true}
];

function initData(data) {
    var item, i;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        item = data[i];
        document.getElementById("termPurchase:" + item.name)[item.field] = item.value;
    }
}

function checkTermDuration(id) {
    if (id == "Days") {
        initData(data1);
    } else {
        initData(data2);
    }
}
```